# How do you add additional layers to a TensorFlow Neural Network?

Tags: tensorflow

How do you add additional layers to a TensorFlow Neural Network and know the additional layer will not be an overfit???  It seems that 2 layers wont be very helpful however it did give me a 91% accuracy and I wanted a 100% accuracy.  So I wanted to add 5 to 10 additional layers and try and "overfit" the neural network.  Would an overfit always give 100% accuracy on a training set?

The basic building block of a neural network is the [*layer*](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers).

I'm using the model example from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

[image: training image set]

The first layer in this network, transforms the format of the images from a two-dimensional array (of 28 by 28 pixels) to a one-dimensional array (of 28 * 28 = 784 pixels). Think of this layer as unstacking rows of pixels in the image and lining them up. This layer has no parameters to learn; it only reformats the data.

Currently this example after the pixels are flattened, the network consists of a sequence of two `tf.keras.layers.Dense` layers or fully connected, neural layers. The first `Dense` layer has 128 nodes (or neurons). The second (and last) layer returns a array with length of 10.

QUESTION: I wanted to start by adding ONE additional layer and then overfit with say 5 layers.  How do manually add an additional layer and fit this layer? can I specify 5 additional layers without having to specify each layer?  Whats a typical estimate for "overfit" on a image data set with a given size of say 30x30 pixels?

Adding One Addtional Layer gave me the same accuracy.

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 9s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4866 - accuracy: 0.8266
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3619 - accuracy: 0.8680
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3278 - accuracy: 0.8785
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3045 - accuracy: 0.8874
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2885 - accuracy: 0.8929
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2727 - accuracy: 0.8980
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2597 - accuracy: 0.9014
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 9s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2475 - accuracy: 0.9061
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 9s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2386 - accuracy: 0.9099
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 10s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2300 - accuracy: 0.9125
```

Comment: Is the correct way to just model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

Answer (score 0):

You can add layers to a neural network as follows.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

**Overfitting**:

Overfitting occurs when a model fits exactly against its training data. When this happens, the algorithm unfortunately cannot perform accurately against unseen data. For example, if our model saw 95% accuracy on the training set but only 45% accuracy on the test set then the model is overfitting against its training data. It does not always give 100% accuracy on a training set.

It can be identified by checking validation metrics such as accuracy and loss.When the model is impacted by overfitting, the validation measures typically rise until a point at which they stagnate or start to decline. The model searches for a good fit during an upward trend, and when it finds one, the trend begins to decline or stagnate. For more information, please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#demonstrate_overfitting).